# Will metatags coming up twice with module hurt my SEO?

Tags: html, drupal, seo, drupal-modules

I have my metatags hand coded in my index.php(page.tpl.php in drupal).  Now, I want to use a module called "nodewords" that allows metatags in every individual page; as opposed to just the index page for the whole site.  But, now it outputs it as something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr"> 

<meta name="Description" content="Hollywood Nose has before and after plastic surgery of all hollywood stars, people/celebrities who should have plastic surgery, celebrity nose jobs, breast augmentation, hairpieces, face lifts, liposuction, and more.  Plastic surgery information includes: forums on top plastic surgeons, patient surgery experiences, the best doctors, and more."> 
<meta name="Keywords" content="Plastic surgery, plastic surgeons, noses, Hollywood, surgeons, Hollywood nose jobs, Hollywood plastic surgery, celebrity hair pieces, celebrity face lift, before and after, plastic surgery, plastic surgeons, best doctors, implants, breast augmentation, celebrity breast implants, hair piece, rhynoplasty, hollywood facelift">    

<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
 <title>Hollywood Nose</title> 
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<meta name="keywords" content="Alicia Keys, nose job, rhinoplasty, plastic surgery, before and after, musician, celebrity., Nose Jobs" /> 
<meta name="description" content="Alicia Keys nose job plastic surgery before and after.  See Alicia Keys when she was young with her original nose and later on after her rhinoplasty." /> 
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Hollywood-Nose/199540186756971"/>
```

Notice that the metatags are listed twice.  Once for the main index(listed on every page), and once for the module including it for the individual page.  My question is, does this hurt my SEO by having it twice?  I already am pretty well indexed my the search engines and wouldn't want to jeopardize that.  Thank you.
`

Comment: that website has a flipping horrifying design to be perfectly honest.

Answer (score 2):

You have clearly very invalid HTML code and you're worried about SEO? I'd worry about my site rendering properly first. Who knows how the numerous browsers out there will react to poorly constructed code like that.

But to answer your question, meta tags are not used for ranking purposes anymore so this won't hurt your rankings. However, because the description meta tag can be used as your snippet in your pages' rankings, if you have two of them you don't know how the search engines will react to it. You may get no description or a poor one as the search engines may just use a random snippet from your page.

Bottom line: fix your HTML so there is only one `<html>` and `<head>`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was trying to link that Facebook key to the html header to record LIKE counts and it wasn't rendering.  So, I put it below the HTML xmlns.  That didn't work either.  So, that's why that was there.  I've removed it now though seeing as the count still isn't working.  But, thanks for the response on that.  In drupal the page.tpl.php is for every page, so you need a module to put metatags on each individual page.  I'm afraid of omiting it from the page.tpl.php and moving it to the module so it only renders on the front page.  I'm afraid that process will hurt the SEO.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above it *can* hurt your ranking. You should definitely remove any meta tags hardcoded via the HTML and manually assign them via Nodewords.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off with only one set although Meta tags don't have anything like the indexing value today that they used to.

Comment: Well, if I deleted them from the index.php and replaced them in the page-front.tpl.php then put them in manually in every page... would that hurt my SEO temporatily?  That's what I'm afraid of.  Cause after like 2 months it's finally really moving up in the alexa ranks.

Comment: @Graham I'm busy now but will come back to you later. This is an area I believe I know a lot about and am happy to share with you.

Answer (score 0):

Found this:

> Myth 6: "If I repeat my Keywords and Descriptions in a comment tag I will rank better."
>
> There was a time when this technique was in vogue for search engines, which may have read and indexed comment tags. Today we know that it's safer to refrain from code, which may be misconstrued as spam. There is no need to repeat your tags.

[here](http://www.pandia.com/optimization/SEO-metatags.html). From what I've seen it may classify as spam then.